# Do 「AとしてのB」 and 「BとしてのA」 have symmetry?

Tags: set-phrases

- 「AとしてのB」 might translate as "B as A"?
- 「BとしてのA」 might translate as "A as B"?

Is there a meaningful difference between the two.

I was just thinking about how to explain how to write documents in English, and this is the sentence that I was writing:
「*分詞としての形容詞や副詞をよく使えば、活発的な文章になります。*」
but then it occurred to me that I perhaps should write:
「*形容詞や副詞としての分詞をよく使えば*、....」

Is this "six of one and half a dozen of the other"? maybe a difference in nuance?

original sentence:
"*The usage of participles as adjectives and adverbs creates more active sentences.*"

Comment: It reminds me a pattern @snailboat found, -- 連体形の形容詞≒形容詞の連体形.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as the English "A as B" is not symmetrical, so is Japanese "BとしてのA." B is the usage/disguise. A is the object to be used.

> 分詞としての形容詞や副詞をよく使えば

does not make sense.

> 形容詞や副詞としての分詞をよく使えば

would be a better translation for your English sentence. However, it is unnatural to fit everything into a noun. It is far more natural to use an adverbial expression like:

> 形容詞や副詞として分詞をよく使えば

or even more naturally:

> 分詞を形容詞や副詞としてよく使えば